# Android Scale Problem

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made the relative  layout and I used fill-parent , wrap-content and for some margin I have to use "dp".

But When I check on different devices the scale/density change So on surfing from Android Developer site I found that I have to defined layouts like

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

So is there any easy or smart trick for density problem without define these layouts... and work wll on all devices with only one standard layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need those different layout folders for density problems. You need those layouts for defining different looks for different screen sizes. If you want to use different images for different densities, you need add images with different resolution to the `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-ldpi` folders.

Android automatically selects images from right folder depending on screen density.

1. drawable-xhdpi - density higher than 240
2. drawable-hdpi - density 240
3. drawable-mdpi - density 160
4. drawable-ldpi - density 120

Start your designing process always for medium density screens.

Comment: I have used drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi folders as you said but my problem is scaling means in large/medium screen it looks as I want but when I chceck on small screen it got conjusted and it didn't give the feeling as it should give

Comment: @user815249 Then you do not have a density problem. Rather you have a problem fitting your design into small screen devices. Then you need use those layout folders indeed. You need to design different UI for small screen devices and add it to layout-small folder.

Comment: I think this is only way, if you want to support wider range of devices. Also you could drop support for small screen devices...

Comment: :I have another query that the view I got in Graphic Layout and the view i got in any device(small or large) is different...so is that ok or I will get problem in future.

Comment: didn't quite understand your question. You mean, if your layout looks different in device that you designed, if this causing problems?